# Why am I getting a green part in the view

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

After trying everything possible to overlap the Green part in my View, I'm still getting this small part, How do I get rid of this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/barcode_scanner"
        android:name="info.androidhive.barcode.BarcodeReader"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:auto_focus="true"
        app:use_flash="false" />

    <info.androidhive.barcode.ScannerOverlay
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="#916e6e6e"
        app:line_color="#7323DC"
        app:line_speed="6"
        app:line_width="2"
        app:square_height="450"
        app:square_width="350" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Here is the Green thing that I want to get rid of.]

Comment: Many users have the same issue. please check it here https://github.com/ravi8x/Barcode-Reader/issues/13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this problem before you can add this xml and testing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">




<fragment
    android:id="@+id/barcode_scanner"
    android:name="info.androidhive.barcode.BarcodeReader"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    app:auto_focus="true"
    app:use_flash="false" />

<info.androidhive.barcode.ScannerOverlay
    android:id="@+id/b"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="#916e6e6e"
    app:line_color="#7323DC"
    app:line_speed="6"
    app:line_width="4"
    app:square_height="450"
    app:square_width="350" />


   </RelativeLayout>
```

Happy Coding ;)